# Close all other jQueryUI tooltips when a new tooltip is opened

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

How can I close all other jQueryUI tooltips when a user opens a new tooltip.  I want to avoid littering the UI with open tooltips.

I did not want to clutter up what I thought was a straightforward question but my tooltips are customized to only show when a user has clicked on a help icon or field name as in the example below.  In addition as in the example, the help triggers are not in the [label] tag associated to that input and so the tooltip can't count on the field focus.  I suspect that is the issue.

```js
function loadCSS(filename) {

  var file = document.createElement("link");
  file.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  file.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  file.setAttribute("href", filename);
  document.head.appendChild(file);

}

loadCSS("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css");


// Disable HOVER tooltips for input elements since they are just annoying.
$("input[title]").tooltip({
  disabled: true,
  content: function() {
    // Allows the tooltip text to be treated as raw HTML.
    return $(this).prop('title');
  },
  close: function(event, ui) {
    // Disable the Tooltip once closed to ensure it can only open via click.
    $(this).tooltip('disable');
  }
});


/* Manually Open the Tooltips */
$(".ui-field-help").click(function(e) {
  var forId = e.target.getAttribute('for');
  if (forId) {
    var $forEl = $("#" + forId);
    if ($forEl.length)
      $forEl.tooltip('enable').tooltip('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-field-help {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td for="A000" class="ui-field-help">First</td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="A000" title="title @A000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td for="B000" class="ui-field-help">Second</td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="B000" title="title @B000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td for="C000" class="ui-field-help">Third</td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="C000" title="title @C000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td for="D000" class="ui-field-help">Fourth</td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="D000" title="title @D000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td for="E000" class="ui-field-help">Fifth</td>
    <td><input type="Text" id="E000" title="title @E000"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The normal behaivor is to close when no longer "over" the tooltip. https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ So I guess without seeing your code, I cannot understand why you'd need to "close" a tooltip in this case. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty, Added code sample to reproduce and realized that the jQueryUI tool tip depends on the focus exit to close the tooltip.   I break that because I manually open the tooltips from a help link outside that field which never triggers the focus.

Comment: Ok, I see that. So you can trigger a close manually in the same sort of way. What event would you like to trigger the close?

Comment: @Twisty, That is a good question.  My initial answer would have been OnOpen of the next tooltip but I am considering reworking the UI so that the tooltip code will work as designed instead of having to hack it, now that I understand what the problem is....

Comment: @Twisty, Thanks for your help.   But I guess this is an question that won't ever get an answer...

Comment: I would think it would be based on `blur` for the item that was clicked. Did you end up reworking it? If so maybe consider deleting the question. Otherwise edit and update.

Comment: @Twisty, yes I reworked it so that the users click on a help icon inside the label that is connected to the specified input.  The label triggers the focus and the Tooltip takes it from there.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

What I was asking for was unnecessary.  If used correctly jQueryUI tooltips will automatically close themselves based on the focus/hover events.

If the tooltip is opened without triggering these events then there won't be any way for it to automatically close itself.

I had intentionally opened the tooltips via a click on a separate help icon.  That click did not trigger the focus.   By fixing my code to move the icon into the LABEL (for=) tied to the INPUT, it resulted in the INPUT receiving the focus which then gave the jQueryUI tooltip widget what it needed to manage the visibility.